# File uploaded to salesforce empty using python and simple_salesforce

Tags: python, salesforce

I'm trying to upload a file to the Folder object in salesforce using python and simple_salesforce. The file is uploaded but is empty. can anyone tell me why and how to fix the problem? Thanks.

```
import base64
import json
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

userName = 'username'
passWord = 'password'
securitytoken = 'securitytoken'

sf=Salesforce(username='userName', password='passWord', security_token='securitytoken', sandbox = True)
sessionId = sf.session_id

body = ""
with open("Info.txt", "r") as f:
    body = base64.b64encode(f.read())

response = requests.post('https://cs17.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v23.0/sobjects/Document/',
headers = { 'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization':'Bearer %s' % sessionId},
data = json.dumps({
    'Description':'Information',
    'Keywords':'Information',
    'FolderId': '00lg0000000MQykAAG',
    'Name': 'Info',
    'Type':'txt'
    })
)

print response.text
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code above, your request is incomplete.  You create the body value as the b64encoding iof the file you wish to upload, but it isn't included in your data associated with a 'body' key.

Depending on your version of json, you may experience some problems getting the output to play nice with Salesforce.  I switched from json to simplejson and that worked better for me.